# Limit image proportions with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
```

The HTML code is structured as follows.
In this case, if an image with a ratio of 1:1 is not entered in the input, I want to move to another page through JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to add a handler for the input, and check if the `height/width === 1`, you can use this function to validate it:

```js
const fileUpload = document.getElementById("file");

function validateImage(target) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[0]);
  reader.onload = function (e) {

    const image = new Image();
    image.src = e.target.result;

    image.onload = function () {
      const height = this.height;
      const width = this.width;
      
      if (height / width !== 1) {
        console.log("ASPECT RATIO NOT 1:1");
        window.location.href = "#otherpage"; // redirect
        return false;
      }
      
      // do nothing
      return true;
    };
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"  onchange="validateImage(this)">
```

Note that this is a very simple validation, normally you would want to add error handlers (e.g. invalid file, broken image, etc.).